# Adding a javascript script tag some place so that it works for every file in sphinx documentation

Tags: javascript, python, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to write some notes. I am using the Mathjax extension for Math in the notes. The default size of the math is little larger than I would like. On the Mathjax page I found that I can change that size by adding the following script to the HTML file.

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {scale: 90}
});
```

So, I tried by adding the following in a `.rst` file:

```
.. raw:: html

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            "HTML-CSS": {
                scale: 90
            }
        });
    </script>

==========
Objective
==========

To change math size \\( \\alpha \\).
```

The above works great for the math in that specific `.rst` file. But I want to do this for many different .rst files that are all part of the same sphinx document. Is it possible to do this without adding the above script to every `.rst` file?

Thank you for reading this and would appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be done with a template:

1. Create a folder called `templates` in the Sphinx project directory.
2. In conf.py, add

   ```
   templates_path = ["templates"]
   ```
3. In the `templates` directory, create a file called `layout.html` with the following contents:

   ```
   {% extends "!layout.html" %}

   {%- block extrahead %} 
    <script type="text/javascript">
          MathJax.Hub.Config({
              "HTML-CSS": {
                  scale: 90
              }
          });
     </script>      
   {% endblock %}
   ```

The `<script>` element will be included in the `<head>` of every generated HTML page.

The `extrahead` template block is empty by default. See the [Sphinx templating documentation](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/templating.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked great! Thanks especially for the detailed steps. Why is there a `-` in the line `{%- block extrahead}`. Without the dash, it does not work. The code examples I have seen in the link do not have this `-`.

Comment: The default `extrahead` block in sphinx/themes/basic/layout.html has the extra hyphen/dash/minus (it is about [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#whitespace-control)). But I can't really explain why it does not work for you without it...

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that. Anyhow, it works great with the dash. Thanks again for responding.

Comment: I did **not** need the dash. This worked great for adding the Tex extension `mhchecm.js` to so I could use `\ce` tex tags to create chemical equations using [mhchem](ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf).

Comment: The latest [MathJax docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-in-line-configuration-options) say to use `"text/x-mathjax-config"` as the script type instead of `"text/javascript"` EG `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid altering templates, you can just call Sphinx's [`add_js_file()`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_js_file) from the `setup()` function in your Sphinx project's [conf.py](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/usage/quickstart.html#basic-configuration):

```
# conf.py

# ... other settings ...

def setup(app):
    # (create a setup() function if you don't already have one;
    # or add to the existing setup() ...)
    app.add_js_file("mathjax-config.js")
```

Create the file "mathjax-config.js" in your _static source directory. (Check the conf.py [`html_static_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_static_path) setting to verify the static directories, or define one if needed.) Sphinx will copy it into the output directory during the build.

There's also an [`add_css_file()`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_css_file) method for css files. And both of them can take either relative paths to your static source dirs, or full urls to external resources.

Before Sphinx v1.8, these functions were called [`add_javascript()`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.2/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_javascript) and [`add_stylesheet()`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.2/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_stylesheet).

And in Sphinx v3.0 or later, there's an [even simpler approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63584965/647002) that avoids the need for an extra JS file.

Comment: It seems this requires setting up an extension, is that correct?

Comment: No extension required: you can place a `setup()` function in your project's own conf.py. (Your project is effectively allowed to be its own extension.)

Comment: @medmunds What is the content of the `mathjax-config.js` supposed to be in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @lcnittl the JS file can contain whatever additional configuration you need. Using the example from the original question at the top of this page, it could be something like `MathJax.Hub.Config({...` etc. (If you need help with specific MathJax options, it's probably better to ask a new question.)

Comment: @medmunds thanks for your answer! I was initially not sure where the problem came form (is the content of the js file incorrect, or is there a problem in 'running' it), but now I got to work what I need with [@mzjn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454654/4233229). I might indeed open up a new question to find the problem (your newer answer does also not work for my usecase), because I think your solution is slicker/more lightweight.

Comment: @medmunds I will certainly open a new question (may take a while though) as I got it to work with your new answer. What was needed in that case was addition of an additional attribute `type="text/x-mathjax-config"`. Cheers.

Comment: @medmunds I have solved it now. It is not worth another question, but I think it would be nice if you could include it in your answer(s), as otherwise they will not work. The method of this answer needs a `window.MathJax = {...}` instead of a `MathJax.Hub.Config({...})` to work properly, as MathJax is not necessarily initiated at that point or not accessible from the `mathjax-config.js` script (cf. https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/configuration.html#using-plain-javascript ). Thanks for considering an edit!

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

Use the [script_files](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/templating.html#script_files) setting in your overridden `layout.html` file.

Answer (score 1):

In Sphinx 3.0 and later, the *easiest* way to add short snippets of JavaScript configuration is to call [`app.add_js_file(None, body="...JS code...")`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/3.x/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_js_file) in your conf.py setup function. Example:

```py
# In your Sphinx project's conf.py:

# 1. Add whatever JS code you need as a string constant.
#    (This example is from the original question.)
MATHJAX_CONFIG_JS = """
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {scale: 90}
});
"""

# 2. Create a setup() function if you don't already have one.
#    (If you do, just add to your existing setup() function.)
def setup(app):
    # 3. Tell Sphinx to add your JS code. Sphinx will insert
    #    the `body` into the html inside a <script> tag:
    app.add_js_file(None, body=MATHJAX_CONFIG_JS)
```

With this approach, you don't need to create a separate, static JS file.

(The `body` param was added in Sphinx 3.0; with earlier versions you can
still use [`add_js_file()`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/3.x/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_js_file) with a static JS file—see my
[earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41885884/647002). And for for anything longer than
a short config snippet, it's probably better to use an external file anyway.)

Comment: It's me again :) I think that in this case a `type="text/x-mathjax-config"` is mandatory, as MathJax's initiation will run those scripts (cf. https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/configuration.html#using-in-line-configuration-options ). Also here, thanks for considering an edit!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for a `conf.py` only configuration might be to use the MathJax extension's config value [`mathjax_config`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/math.html#confval-mathjax_config) (Available since `1.8`).
The value of `mathjax_config` is passed to [`MathJax.Hub.Config()`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/configuration.html#using-in-line-configuration-options).

In your specific case, add the following to `conf.py`:

```py
mathjax_config = {
    "HTML-CSS": {"scale": 90},
}
```