# MathJax extension mhchem in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax

How do you enable `MathJax` extension `mhchem` in `Sphinx`? MathJax is loaded from `CDN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following block into your rst file. Or see [Adding a javascript script tag some place so that it works for every file in sphinx documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444342/adding-a-javascript-script-tag-some-place-so-that-it-works-for-every-file-in-sph) to add it into your template, so it can be applied globally.

```
.. raw:: html

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        TeX: { extensions: ["mhchem.js"] }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: When I add this directly, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined`. So it looks like Sphinx by default doesn't define MathJax even though I'm able to use it. More specifically, MathJax script isn't guaranteed to load before the raw html is run.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem for all rst files, I 'subclassed' mathjax... AKA, I made another js file in my _static directory that would load mathjax then manually add the extension I needed (cancel in my case). Then I specified that path for the `mathjax_path` option in the conf.py. The contents of mathjax_config.js are:

```
// Dynamically load script then call helper when script has loaded.
function dynamicallyLoadScript(url, helper) {
    var script = document.createElement("script"); // Make a script DOM node
    script.src = url; // Set it's src to the provided URL

    document.head.appendChild(script); // Add it to the end of the head section of the page (could change 'head' to 'body' to add it to the end of the body section instead)
    script.onreadystatechange= function () {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete') helper();
     }
     script.onload= helper;
}

// Configure MathJax
function mathjax_config() {
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
  MathJax.Hub.Insert(MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Definitions.macros,{
    cancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
    bcancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
    xcancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
    cancelto: ["Extension","cancel"]
    });
  });
}
var mathjax_url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
dynamicallyLoadScript(mathjax_url, mathjax_config)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [Sunhwan Jo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22304162/4039050) hasn't worked for me, here's my attempt to address this:

```
.. math::

   \require{mhchem}
   \ce{E + S <=> ES -> ES* -> E + P}
```

I think it's simple and elegant. Besides, you don't need to call `\require{mhchem}` more than once in a single `.rst` file.