# How to include a webix table into a sphinx html document?

Tags: html, python-sphinx, webix

I would like to include a webix table such as this [one](http://webix.com/demo/datatable/frozen-columns/) into a sphinx document.

I've found that directive:

```
.. raw::
    :file: data.html
```

Unfortunately it does not work because the `head` should be included into `<head>`. Also the relative links should be updated according to the sphinx generated html.

```
<head>
    <title>"Find" API</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webix.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="webix.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="samples.css">
    <script src="testdata.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

How to include a webix widget into a static sphinx page?

One possible solution would be to fully include the html using jquery:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

However this requires to add stuff into the `<head>` of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is create a custom HTML theme for use in Sphinx.  This is less work than it sounds like, since you can probably just inherit from an existing theme, and only override a small part of it in your new theme.  See the Sphinx docs re: [templating](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html) and [theming](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html)

Also, see this answer, which might be helpful:
[Adding a javascript script tag some place so that it works for every file in sphinx documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444342/adding-a-javascript-script-tag-some-place-so-that-it-works-for-every-file-in-sph)